# Why is "create" undefined for Edge extension notifications?

Tags: notifications, undefined, microsoft-edge, microsoft-edge-extension

Running code in Edge extension throws a TypeError, unable to get property 'create' of undefined or null reference.

I have tried running it in both the popup and background scripts. I have the notifications permissions in the manifest. I did see that some APIs require being run in the content script, but since I'm not engaging the tabs or web pages, I don't think that applies to me...?

Manifest:

```
{
  "name": "xxx",
  "author": "xxx", "version": "1.1",
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["jquery-3.3.1.min.js","background.js"], "persistent": true
  },
  "permissions": [
    "xxx",
    "background",
    "notifications",
    "storage"

  ],
  "offline_enabled": true,
  "browser_action": {
      "default_title": "xxx",
      "default_popup": "popup.html",
      "default_icon": "32.png"
  },
  "manifest_version": 2
}
```

Background script:

```
try{
    browser.notifications.create("test",{
    "type": "basic",
    "title": "Test",
    "iconUrl": "48.png",
    "message": "This is a test"
    });
}catch(e){
    alert(e);
}
```

Comment: What's the Edge browser version? From [this article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/API/notifications/create), it seems that the notifications.create() method support Edge 17+, please check your Edge browser version, make sure it achieves the requirement.

Comment: that might be it then. I have Edge 41, but EdgeHTML 16.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, first, you could try to upgrade the Edge browser to the latest version, then, try to use the browser.notifications.create method.

But, in my opinion, I prefer to display the notification using the Web Notifications API, you could check [this article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/windows-integration/web-notifications-api).

Comment: you can use that API with extensions? I tried using it at one point with my extension and didn't work -- i thought it was only for web pages. maybe i can take another crack at it. also, unfortunately company group policy dictates browser version and we haven't upgraded to that version yet, so i may just have to hold tight for now on using the create property. thanks!